# Reading a column in Excel with different types of information on each row

Tags: c#, excel, winforms

I'm trying to read an Excel document with a program that I've written and based off the read information, changes certain fields on my UI and I'm running into an interesting problem.

One of my columns has the potential to hold 4 different types of data. Each cell in the row might contain a number, a number stored as text, text, or nothing.

This is the section of code I'm using to read this column:

```
try
{
    string dtTerritory = dt.Rows[0].Field<string>("Territory");
    cmbTerritory.SelectedItem = dtTerritory;
    territory = dtTerritory;
}
catch
{
    double dtTerritory = dt.Rows[0].Field<double>("Territory");
    cmbTerritory.SelectedItem = dtTerritory.ToString();
    territory = dtTerritory.ToString();
}
```

The issue I am running into is reading a number stored as text, and the issue is that, when the numbers are stored as text on the Excel sheet, it is always stored as 3 characters. So if the number is 3, it is stored as "3  " (2 spaces after the 3) if it is 46, it is stored as "46 " (1 space after the 46).

So I'm essentially looking for the best solution on how I can have my program ignore the spaces that occur after the number. Any ideas?

Comment: why couldn't you just do `ToString() of the Field<string>("Territory")`
`string dtTerritory = dt.Rows[0].Field<string>("Territory").ToString();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd just read the data as text and then do processing on it to see if you can convert it to a number or not.

So in the first instance you need to trim the text:

```
dtTerritory = dtTerritory.Trim();
```

Then check to see if it's then an empty string:

```
if (!string.IsEmptyOrWhileSpace(dtTerritory))
{
    // Process further
}
```

Then your further processing is to try to parse the text:

```
double value;
if (double.TryParse(dtTerritory, out value))
{
    // do your double value handling here.
}
```

Comment: This worked to accomplish what I was looking to do. Thanks!